# Caching variables in isolated storage, portable class library way

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I'm trying to figure out how I can read and write params that gets stored in the applications isolated storage.

Right now im building a windows phone app, but since I want a win8 app to I figured I could do it in portable class library project, and found this awesome [PCLStorage](https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/).

My Cache class looks atm like this for storing params:

```
    public async static Task<string> GetParam(string name)
    {
        IFolder rootfolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder folder = await rootfolder.GetFolderAsync("isostore");
        IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(name);

        return await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
    }

    public async static void SaveParam(string name, string param)
    {
        IFolder rootfolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder folder = await rootfolder.CreateFolderAsync("isostore", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        await file.WriteAllTextAsync(param);
    }
```

The write part is okey, it overrides if there is any. Its the reading part that is the problem. IFile and IFolder does not have any `.Exists` functions (???) so what does it return if I call Get before Save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case in the `GetParam` method you should be calling CreateFolderAsync and CreateFileAsync with the CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists parameter.  Then you shouldn't need to worry about creating them separately beforehand or catching exceptions that they do/don't exist.